# Javascript: Detect when an alert box is OK'ed and/or closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect when a javascript alert box is OK'ed and/or closed?

Comment: You mean confirm()? An alert box is only shown to notify about something (in a pretty ugly way, but hey …) and does not return anything.

Comment: What did you try? Anything simple/silly you would have tried would have worked, because the answer is very simple: you don't detect. the browser does it for you: waits with the alert before it does anything else.

Comment: +1 becuase this one is really interesting ...

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Since `alert` is blocking:

```
alert('foo');
function_to_call_when_oked_or_closed();
```

Just put the function after the call to `alert`.

Answer (score 18):

You can show a `confirm box` that displays a message with an OK and a Cancel button and check which button the user clicked by:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var answer = confirm ("Is this working for you?")
if (answer)
    alert ("Woo Hoo! Then my answer was correct.")
else
    alert ("Darn. Well, keep trying then.")

</script>
```

If you want to make use of a simple **alert box** you can have a look at 1001 tutorials online such as [this](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptalert.php) one for example. But your question does not specify how exactly you want to implement your `alert`.

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptalert.php

Comment: Really helpful for me

Answer (score 2):

If user didn't press ok or close, the JS will not proceed to the next line. So actually there is no need to detect this.

Maybe you want to know if the user pressed ok or close. For the alert popup box, there is no easy way to tell it is ok'ed or closed. In Firefox, you don't even have the close button.

So if you really want to do this, you can use Confirm Box or Prompt Box.
Please check the link below for how to use Confirm Box or Prompt Box:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp