# How to reload a page after the OK click on the Alert Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, page-refresh

I need to reload the page after the OK button is clicked on the Alert box. 
I am using the following code for it

```
alert("Successful Message");
window.location.reload();
```

But the window is reloaded immediately after displaying the alertbox. Please Help me in it

Comment: Use a `prompt` instead of an `alert`

Comment: Perhaps help you this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146028/detect-when-an-alert-box-is-oked-and-or-closed

Comment: Are you reloading this window after form submission response comes back?

Comment: What you have should work. `alert` is blocking. I bet your browser is blocking the pop-up and so it immediately proceeds to the next line. The recommended answers of using an if for alert are not necessary.

Answer (score 67):

Confirm gives you chance to click on cancel, and reload will not be done!

Instead, you can use something like this:

```
if(alert('Alert For your User!')){}
else    window.location.reload();
```

This will display alert to your user, and when he clicks OK, it will return false and reload will be done! :)
Also, the shorter version:

```
if(!alert('Alert For your User!')){window.location.reload();}
```

I hope that this helped!? :)

Comment: FYI. "if(!alert('Alert For your User!')){window.location.reload();}"

this works, this should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 14):

Use javascript `confirm()` method instead of alert. It returns `true` if the user clicked ok button and returns `false` when user clicked on cancel button. Sample code will look like this :

```
if(confirm('Successful Message')){
    window.location.reload();  
}
```

Comment: I don't want a cancel button.. The page needed to be refreshed Just after clicking ok... Confirm will give the Cancel button too

Answer (score 8):

Use a confirm box instead.

```
var r = confirm("Successful Message!");
if (r == true){
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
alert('Alert For your User!') ? "" : location.reload();
```

You can write above code in this format also.It seems quite decent

Comment: Why use added this here `? "" :`?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Ternery operator. Same usage as if else in just one like. ES6 implementation .

Comment: @yashas123 But if we are using the *ternary operator* with `alert()` then it will always trigger the else part as the `alert()` always returns `false`, Isn't it?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Best to use ```window.onbeforeunload = function() { whatever you want to do }```

Answer (score 2):

Bojan Milic answer work in a way but it error out with a message below,

[image]

This can be avoid with,

```
function message() 
{
alert("Successful message");
window.location = 'url_Of_Redirected_Page' // i.e. window.location='default.aspx'
}
```

Comment: This will solve the problem: window.location.href = window.location.href;

Answer (score 0):

As the alert method in JavaScript does not return a Boolean or yield the current thread, you must use a different method.

My number one recommendation requires a little CSS experience. You should instead create a div element that is fixed positionally.

Otherwise you could use the confirm() method.

```
confirm("Successful Message");
window.location.reload();
```

However, this will add a cancel button. Because the confirm method is not within an if statement though, the cancel button will still refresh the page like you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that Firefox will stop further processing of JavaScript after the relocate function.  Chrome and IE will continue to display any other alerts and then reload the page.  Try it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('foo');
    window.location.reload(true);
    alert('bar');
    window.location.reload(true);
    alert('foobar');
    window.location.reload(true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert("Successful Message");
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here but I had the same problem, after spending more time than I'm proud of I realised I had set chrome to block all pop ups and hence kept reloading without showing me the alert box. So close your window and open the page again.

If that doesn't work then you problem might be something deeper because all the solutions already given should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

IN PHP Code

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>".
      "alert('Success to add the task to a project.');
       location.reload;".
     "</script>";
```

IN Javascript

```
function refresh()
{
    alert("click ok to refresh  page");
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: location.reload is a method not property see your php code.

Comment: Okay , But this code is working fine for me in my project. and this way you can solve your main question problem.. by the way thank for your time..