# JavaScript Popup Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to PHP and script and have come across a problem that I can’t resolve.

I have a booking page that users tick a checkbox to book times. The on submit button then runs a script to check if they have booked the number of times that they asked for. So if asked for 3 booking times and they have only select 2 it fires the alert window. On pressing OK the window should reload so they can select again. This works great in Firefox and will reload all the select checkboxes are cleared.

However if you do this in IE and chrome the alert box hijacks the page and the window still has the checkbox’s selected.

```
function CheckBox() {
  try {

    var max = document.mainForm.serNo.length;
    var count = 0;
    var tot = <?php echo $Num ?>;

    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      if (document.mainForm.serNo[i].checked == true) {
        count++;
        serNoChecked = i;
      }
    }

    if (count < tot) {
      for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        window.alert('THERE IS A PROBLEM WITH YOUR BOOKING. \n You have asked to book ' + tot +  ' times, but have only selected ' + count + ' times.\n Please re-select the same number of times as asked at the start or re-start your booking');

        window.location.assign("url");
      }
    }     

  } catch (e) {
     alert(e.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want to reload the page i suggest `location.reload(true)` this 'should' clear the checkboxes

Comment: Thats Kevin, Still doen't work, The alert box still stays when the page re-loads

Comment: [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955019/how-to-reload-a-page-after-the-ok-click-on-the-alert-page)

Comment: Thanks Again Kev, Didn't work. Internest this did just keep going in a loop in IE. In firefox, it stop after the first message and loaded the page. alert('foo');
    window.location.reload(true);
    alert('bar');
    window.location.reload(true);
    alert('foobar');
    window.location.reload(true);

Comment: remind me, why is the alert and reload in a for loop?

Comment: It shouldn't, Firefox works OK, I.E and Chrome seem to loop the alert box. When I tried the alert(foo) etc, Firefox didnt loop it, but IE did and the message just kept going around.

Comment: it shouldn't loop, than why is it in a for loop?

Comment: Does the code in the first post suggest a loop becasue it shouldn't.

Comment: yes `if (count < tot) {
      for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        window.alert('your alert');
        window.location.assign("url");
      }
    }` loops as long as i < max, assuming max is 3 the loop would be executed 3 times

Comment: $Num is the number of books they want, If they select less than I need an alert message to popup and say that. Once they click Ok I need the page to re-load and not go onto the next page. If the number select = the $num the it can move on.

Comment: Why reload the page? You can reset the form by calling `document.mainForm.reset()`.

Answer (score 0):

you have a loop which is giving multiple times the popup, this is redundant.

also the use of `location.reload(true)` is suggested as the `true`parameter reloads the current page from the server instead of from the cache.

the `if(!alert("your text")){}` checks if the alert box is not closed, when closed it executes the `window.reload(true)`

the submit button and form must have a unique id for this.

i have posted the updated code below:

```
document.getElementById("mySubmitButtonId").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  try {
    event.preventDefault();
    var max = document.mainForm.serNo.length;
    var count = 0;
    var tot = <?php echo $Num ?>;

    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      if (document.mainForm.serNo[i].checked == true) {
        count++;
        serNoChecked = i;
      }
    }

    if (count !== tot) {
        if(!alert('THERE IS A PROBLEM WITH YOUR BOOKING. \n You have asked to book ' + tot +  ' times, but have only selected ' + count + ' times.\n Please re-select the same number of times as asked at the start or re-start your booking')){
        window.location.reload(true);
        }
      } else {
            document.getElementById("myFormId").submit();
        }

    } catch (e) {
     alert(e.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks again Kevin. It works great in IE, and I suspect Chrome. But now Firefox shows the message, but then moves on to the comformation page, when it should re-load this page. I have aslo just tested the IE when all ccorrect number of times are checked and it comes up with IE canot opne the URl page Option aborted.

Comment: that is a feature in the browser to prevent people from accidentally losing data they are sending to the server, as far as i know you can't disable this popup.

Comment: `This may occur on lower versions of Internet Explorer and to the newly updated ones. This may be a server side or client side issue.` what version of IE are you using?

Comment: Why isn't it working with Firefox, if I wanted 3 times, but only select 2 it gives the waring and that move to the conformation page. It should re-load this page. I tried the IE agian and it worked, Properly me playing around with it.

Comment: i have edited my answer, and `document.mainForm.serNo.length` = how much checkboxes there are and `<?php echo $Num ?>` is how much you are allowed select, right?

Comment: The $num the number of bookings they have asked for. They then pick  times from a list of availabe time. Once they pick 3 or how many slots  they want to book all the checkboxes grey out. If they have asked for 3 but only 2 picked I want to warn them.  You can see the form from this link, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/144531/Untitled.png

Comment: couldn't you prevent the user from submitting with an onsubmit event? that would be much easier.

Comment: Do you mean the submit buitton, This is what I have <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Make Booking' onclick='CheckBox()'>

Comment: @Rik i have updated my answer with the onsubmit event. P.s. the onclick in your submit button can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me with this. The onclick was pointing to the function, No I have taken the onclick off the page goes straight to the confirm page. Are you saying that the code above needs to go with the Booking Button. If so I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: yes the code above needs to be executed with the event handler for click on the submit button. as said in the answer the form and the submit button both need an unique id. instead of the onclick in the html page here is a onclick in the javascript, event is passed in the function bound to it, the default handling of the submit button is prevented and if the `count == tot` the form will be submitted. anything you don't understand about this?

Comment: I have tried to work this out, but failing badly, The popup is working in Firefox, but not IE. In Firefox if correct number of booking made I get "document.getElementById(...) is null" . Form is <form action='#' name='mainForm' method='post'> and button is now <input type='submit_button' id='Book' name='submit_but' value='Make Booking' >. So I need a function above the document .getelementByid somelike window.onload = function()? As I said I am new to this.

Comment: you get the error because you have not specified an id for the form, `<form action='#' name='mainForm' method='post' id="myFormId" >`

Comment: This is driving me nuts, I did add this and it didn't work so took it out, I have added it as you suggested, Firefox popup OK if not enough booking made, but if the correct number made the page just reload again. In Internet Explorer I get webpage has expired :( I have changed the button to <input type='submit' id='Book' name='submit_but' value='Make Booking' >

Comment: the webpage has expired is a problem with the caching in ie, [as explained here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183763)

Comment: when the correct number made, does it show the alert?

Comment: NO not in Firefox.

Comment: the form action # could have impact on this try this: `<form action name='mainForm' method='post' id="myFormId" >` and tell me if it still reloads the page or if the submit actually worked.

Comment: Popup box works great in Firefox and chrome. Unfortunatly still only reloading the the same page when correct number of bookings made. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: so, you want to reload the page even if the user has the correct number of bookings?

Comment: NO, If the user books the number of booking they have asked for the page should load a conformation page. As it is now if I pick the right  number it re-loads the page we are on. If I don't select enough booking the warning popup works. I have checked the script, the only thing I don't understand is the extra } before the else statement.

Comment: the extra `}` is to close the if statement, there is an if statement with an if statement nested inside, the else is for the outer most if statement. as far as loading another page you need to specify to where the form is posting using the action attribute [read more about action attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action)

Comment: I presumed that the document.getElementById("myFormId").submit(); would point ito the isset($_POST["submit"]), which has a $updateGoTo = after the insert query. I did read the link and I seem to have it as they say.

Comment: can you add that piece of php to the question? also put an minified version of your html form in the question, that would make it easier to spot the problem

Comment: You can see it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/144531/php.txt

Comment: i notice that your first part of php doesn't have `<?php ?>`, your body tag appears to be missing an `<`, also there are 2 body tags?, also have i noticed that there is some random text inside an redundant php tag. (`if 
  Code for form
  }`) , and the part of `$updateGoTo` is missing.

Comment: I did delete things to cut it down, The <php is there as is the ?>, and the <body> is also there. Hadn't noticed the 2nd Body tag and have deleted it. If I remove the code you kindly gave me and change the name of the button to submit the php works as it should do and updates the sql table and moves to the conformation page.

Comment: you should change this line,

`if(isset($_POST['submit']))`
to this instead,

`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`

Comment: You are a star, I don't understand why the isset method needed to be different and haven't seen if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') before. Could you point me to the describtion, or explain. Either way it works great.

Comment: `$_SERVER` is a PHP super global variable which holds information about headers, paths, and script locations. `['REQUEST_METHOD']` Returns the request method used to access the page. why do you need this instead of the `$_POST`? because the `$_POST` only works when the form is submitted with the submit button, here we have prevented the default behavior of the submit.
[you can read more about super globals here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp)