# Javascript: handle click of alert box

Tags: javascript, http

I would like to catch the click of an alert box and reload the location at this point. Currently I have reload at the end of the function which is not the desired behaviour

```
function myFunction(url, myuser, myprocessing){

var xhr = $.ajax({
"url": url,
"data": { creatio: myuser, reqiu : myprocessing},
"error": 
        function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);              

},
"success": 
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Success"); << ONCLICK of Alert... location.reload(); >>

            if($('#inspect-modal').data('modal').isShown == true) {
                $('#inspect-modal').modal('hide');
            }


}
});
location.reload(); <<remove this>>
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146028/detect-when-an-alert-box-is-oked-and-or-closed SO Search is very good for giving you answers to trivial questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `reload` to after the alert:

```
alert("Success");
location.reload();
```

It shouldn't reload until the user clicks the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Do the `reload` after `alert`. `alert` pauses execution of javascript code until you dismiss it.

```
alert("Success");
location.reload();
```

Comment: thanks! thats the solution...i tried this before posting but i must have ad a typo...