# Understanding how to use callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still new to javascript and Jquery.
I understand that javascript will execute each line as it encounters it.
So in the case (when my value > 9)

- The custom alert will fire off.
- The window.open will immediately execute.

What I would like to happen is for the custom alert to fire off, and once the alert is closed then have the window.open execute.

How can I accomplish this?

```
if ($('#MyCount').val() > 9) {
            MyCustom.alert("MyTitle", " Some text.... ");
            window.open(url, 'Print', "toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no");
}else {
      window.open(url, 'Print', "toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no");
}
```

Comment: What is `MyCustom.alert`? Does it have any events for which you can attach handlers?

Comment: Your custom alert will need to accept a `function reference` as a second parameter the fires off when the close method is triggered.

Comment: Change the `Custom` class' alert method implementation to accept third parameter as callback function, which would be called after lines in `alert` function.

Comment: MyCustom.alert is an in house control that was already written.  So I would need to add a new parameter that will take a function that I pass in, and execute it?

Comment: Is MyCustom.alert just using the native browser `alert`? If so, then I feel like your code would work (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7146074/2679750)).. If it is some custom alert, then you need to pass a function parameter to the alert function (looks like it would be the third parameter), and execute it once alert finishes. (hopefully you have listeners or it's a promise)

Comment: No it's using jquery-ui dialog.

Comment: On the MyCustom.alert I added:
                close: function (callback) {
                    if (callback)
                    {
                        callback;
                    }
                }

Comment: `if (callback) { callback(); }`

Comment: OK. I getting closer but I get error: Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: MyCustom.alert = function (title, msg, callback) {.........close: function (callback) {
                    if (callback)
                    {
                        callback();
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/b9ntt6kL/) together for you.. I hope it makes sense.

We basically pass the callback function as the third parameter to `MyCustom.alert`, and listen for the `'dialogclose` event from jQuery UI.

### HTML

```
<input id="MyCount" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="test" />

<div id="someAlert">
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var MyCustom = {};

MyCustom.alert = function(p1, p2, callback) {
    $("#someAlert").dialog();
    $("#someAlert").children("h1").text(p1);
    $("#someAlert").children("p").text(p2);

    alert(typeof(callback));

    $("#someAlert").on('dialogclose', function(){
        callback();
    });
};

function doSomething(){
 alert("I'm the callback");   
}

var greaterThan9 = function () { 
    if ($('#MyCount').val() > 9) {
                MyCustom.alert("MyTitle", " Some text.... ", doSomething);
                //window.open(url, 'Print', "toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no");
    } else {
    }
}

$("#test").on("click", function(){
   greaterThan9(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#MyCount').val() > 9) {
```

change to

```
var myCount = parseInt($('#MyCount').val());
if (!isNaN(myCount) && myCount > 9) {
```

The rest depends on the implementation of `MyCustom.alert`. If it is a wrapper for javascript native `alert`, then your code will work as is. If it is using an html dialog, you need to pass it a callback to run when it closes.

Comment: Thank you for the javascript cleanup.