# How to combine alert with onclick event

Tags: javascript

Currently I have an alert box that pops up after a period of time. When I click "ok", I'd like to assign that click event to an action such as console.log to record something. I have tried "alert.onclick", but this does not seem to work.
Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Hey Jessica, looks like your question is a duplicate of this one. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146028/javascript-detect-when-an-alert-box-is-oked-and-or-closed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Detect when an alert box is OK'ed and/or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146028/javascript-detect-when-an-alert-box-is-oked-and-or-closed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `window.alert`

## Look at this code snippet

*Of course, the log will be called even if you press esc key.*

```js
var nativeAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(msg) {
  nativeAlert(msg);
  console.log('After OK!! :-)');
};

alert('Hello World!');
```

Answer (score 0):

The alert() does not return nothing if you don't override it. Instead you can use `confirm`

```js
 // result is a  boolean variable

    var result = confirm( "Do you want to continue" );
    
    if ( result ) {
        //  ok is  clicked
        console.log("ok");
    } else {
        // the user clicked cancel or closed the confirm dialog.
    }
```

Another intelligent solution that i've found is this

```js
function function_to_call_when_oked_or_closed () {
console.log("closed");
}

alert('foo');
function_to_call_when_oked_or_closed();
```

this is possible because `alert()` is synchronous (if you don't close it, the code below will not execute. )