# Count up timer to restart the timer once "OK" is clicked in alert box

Tags: javascript

```js
  let hour = 0;
  let minute = 0;
  let seconds = 0;
  let pauseTime = null;
  let start = [...document.cookie.matchAll(/([^;=]+)=([^;=]+)(;|$)/g)].filter(x => x[1].trim() == 'timer').map(x => Number(x[2].trim()))[0];
  if(start != null) {
     if(start > 0) start = new Date(start);
     else if(start < 0) { 
       pauseTime = -start;
       start = new Date(Date.now() + start); //+- = -
     } else start = null;
  } else start = null;
  let intervalId = null;


  function startTimer() {
    let totalSeconds;
    if(pauseTime) {
       start = new Date(Date.now() - pauseTime);
       totalSeconds = pauseTime;
       return;
    } else {
       totalSeconds = Math.floor((Date.now() - start.getTime()) / 1000);
    }
    hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds /3600);
    minute = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour*3600)/60);
    seconds = totalSeconds - (hour*3600 + minute*60);

    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML =hour;
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML =minute;
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML =seconds;
  }
  if(start) intervalId = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);

  document.getElementById('start-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
     if(pauseTime) {
        pauseTime = null;
     } else {
       if(start) return;
       start = new Date();
       intervalId = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
     }
     document.cookie = "timer=" + String(start.getTime());
  })

  document.getElementById('stop-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    pauseTime = Date.now() - start.getTime();
    document.cookie = "timer=" + String(-pauseTime);
    alert("Timer is Currently paused. Press Okay to resume time.");
    document.getElementById("start-btn").click(); 
  });


  document.getElementById('reset-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
     start = null;
     document.cookie = "timer=null";
     if(intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);
     document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '0';
     document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = '0';
     document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = '0';
  });
```

```html
<button id="start-btn">Start</button>
<button id="stop-btn">Pause</button>
<button id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
```

I have a simple app that start, pauses and reset a timer when the appropriate button is clicked. What I am trying to do is create an alert box when the pause button is clicked and once someone clicks OK on the alert box, the timer starts again. I thought simply mimicking selecting the start button again would do this, but instead it starts the time like the pause never occurred. Any suggestion?

Comment: create snippet demo please

Comment: You might want to have a look at the answers here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146028/javascript-detect-when-an-alert-box-is-oked-and-or-closed